# Adding an image into a database using a html form

Tags: php, sql

I am trying to add records into a database. Each record has a corresponding image. The records are getting inserted into the database but it is not working for the image. I am getting this error "connected succesfully
Notice: Undefined variable: sql in C:\xampp\htdocs\Syokimaufc\addplayer.php on line 35
Error: Query was empty" How can i solve this?
HTML form

```
     <p> id: <input type="text" name="playerid"/></p>
     <p> Name: <input type="text" name="name"/></p>
     <p> Age: <input type="text" name="age"/></p>
     <p> Position: <input type="text" name="position"/></p>
     <p> Nationality: <input type="text" name="nationality"/></p>
     <p> Photo: <input type="file" name="image"/></p>
 <input type="submit" value="submit"/>

 <form/>
```

php script

```
    <?php
require 'connection.php';


$id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'playerid');
$name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
$age = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'age');
$position = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'position');
$nationality = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'nationality');

$_id = mysql_real_escape_string( $id );
$_name = mysql_real_escape_string( $name );
$_age = mysql_real_escape_string( $age );
$_position = mysql_real_escape_string( $position );
$_nationality = mysql_real_escape_string( $nationality );

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $imageName = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES ["image"]["iname"]);
    $imageData = mysql_real_escape(file_get_contents($_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"]));
    $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["iname"]);

    if (substr($imageType,0,5) == "image")
    {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO players ( playerid, name, age, position, nationality, iname, image ) VALUES ( '$_id', '$_name', '$_age', '$_position', '$_nationality', '$imageName', '$imageData' )";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "only images are allowed";
    }
}


if (!mysql_query($sql)){
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your form try adding an attribute:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data">
......
..
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it with the name property in the submit ?, it seems that is not going to "if"

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

just check following steps:

1. In html file, a form with image upload should be set with enctype="multipart/form-data"

e.g. `<form enctype="multipart/form-data>`

2. In PHP script

   `$_FILES["image"]["iname"]` is wrong.

   `$_FILES["image"]["name"]` should be the right one.

Comment: $imageType = mysql_real_escape_string($_FILES["image"]["iname"]);

$_FILES['images']['type'] this value is the image type.